# notify-send to display desktop notification from script running as different user

Tags: shell-script, notifications, notify-send

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

notificationMessage="Your session is going to expire soon"
if [ $# == 2 ]; then
  notificationMessage="Your session is going to expire in $2 hour"
fi

# echo "$notificationMessage"

sudo -u userA notify-send "Session Expiration Notification" "$notificationMessage" -u normal -t 10000
```

When I run the above script from a terminal (logged in as **remoteUser**), **userA** is able to see the notification on the screen. However, if the script is executed from a service (run as **remoteUser**), the notification is not shown to **userA**.

Where am I doing things wrong?

***Note: remoteUser has `sudo` privilege***

Answer (score 0):

> However, if the script is being executed from a service (run as remoteUser), the notification is not shown to the userA.

X.org by default limits access to itself to a single active user session. There are different ways to solve this issue:

1. Using `export DISPLAY=:0` and `sudo your_currentuser notification_command`
2. Running `xhost +SI:localuser:remoteUser` under your user session to allow `remoteUser` to run X applications in your session. In your script you will still have to use `export DISPLAY=:0`

More info:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xhost
- https://datacadamia.com/ssh/x11/cygwinx_remote_client
- https://www.bu.edu/tech/services/security/server/vulnerability-management/xprobe/xauth/